# Prevent Simultaneous click on same button in multiuser environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a button. And people can access that button from their system. What I want is: suppose 2 people click on same button at the same time only 1 should be able to access the content which is loaded after button is clicked.

But now what happens is if 2 users click the same button at the same time, both have the access to the page which is loaded after button click.

I want only one person to have access to that button even if 2 are clicking it simultaneously.

Comment: *"What i want is suppose suppose 2 person click on same button at the same time"* Your premise is invalid. Each person viewing your page, will be viewing a separate page running locally on their own system. There will never be just one button that everyone shares.

Comment: The only way to accomplish something like this is to have the button's click event set to call a server-side resource, which will then record that it has been accessed so that any further requests for that resource will not process. Even in this situation, you are not guaranteed that the first person to click their button will get the right response because you will be at the mercy of the network speeds of each user.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you might be new to web applications, and are confusing the system's behavior between those and desktop applications. Take a look on the  [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section before posting anything and (if you need to ask anyway), provide some code and what you have already tried.

Comment: @henriqueromao I don't think there is any problem with how the question was asked. This is more of a lack of understanding of how client-side applications work, not how to ask questions.

Comment: You have simply *asked*. You did not provide anything that you have already **search** or **tried**. It makes easier for us to try really understanding the problem/doubts you are having.

Comment: @henriqueromao While that is generally true, it isn't in this case. It's very obvious that the OP doesn't understand the environment that his code will run in and that he hasn't written any code because he doesn't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all the negative comments, there is a very valid reason and answer to this question; however, it will typically involve adding a server side script and database such as PHP/mySQL or ASP.NET/SQL to handle this behavior.

Your button will need to post to your server side script which will flip a variable in your database to say that the page is in use.  Then when the next request is received, the script will read that variable and perform the exception which is to not deliver the content.  Because of the way data threading works, the server will always pick one to run first, then the other, even if both requests are received on the same clock cycle; so, you will never have them both open the page.

Comment: Thank you for supporting, and yes I was new to web development at that time, also the suggestion which you provided, I followed the same with a twist, I just saved the timestamp at the time button was clicked, and checked if the timestamp is empty or not before fulfilling the request. This is what I did long back.